# convert hand-filled checkbox form to excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf, automation, ocr, handwriting

I got a hand-filled check box form:
[image]

Imagine that there are Xs on each row to represent the selected answer by pen marks.

I look for some kind of software that will convert the scanned forms into excel or csv format.

Comment: Look at different OCR softwares.

Answer (score 0):

I found SimpleOCR and it seems to meet your needs. [About SimpleOCR Freeware](https://www.simpleocr.com/ocr-freeware/)